# D3D9 drawing 100k cubes from Vertexbuffer is very slow

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, direct3d

I'm newbie in this stuff. I'm working with a book which shows me how to use D3D9 and how to create a vertexbuffer and draw a cube from it. I created a class in c++ which wraps the needed stuff to draw a single cube. Means every cube object creats its own vertexbuffer and stores the pointer to vertexbuffer, pos, rotation and scaling values.

The problem is that the drawing of this 100k is very slow. I get only ~2-3 FPS if I try to draw this 100k cubes (with a Nvidia GTX 970)

Instead of writing my long code here i decided to show only the current steps im doing to draw a cube because i think that there is already the mistake. If code is realy need then I will add it for sure. K that are the important steps:

//create vertexbuffer for a single cube obj Object:

```
1.) pDevice->CreateVertexBuffer() //using: D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY
2.) pVertexBuffer->Lock()
3.) memcpy() //copy stuff into vertexbuffer
4.) pVertexBuffer->Unlock();
```

//drawing a cube object (this stuff im called in a for-loop which runs trought the 100k cubes):

```
1.) pDevice->SetFVF()
2.) pDevice->SetStreamSource() //to use the cube's vertexbuffer
3.) create rotation-, translation- and scalingmatrix
4.) create world matrix from the matrix above
5.) pDevice->SetTransform() //use the worldmatrix
6.) pDevice->DrawPrimitive()
```

what I found out is that if I make the vertexbuffer static (means all 100k use the same vertexbuffer) then I get 10 times more fps (~30FPS) But idk.. 100k cubes sounds for me still not much (100k cubes and only 30FPS O_o?). I think im doing something totaly wrong :/

Someone have an idea whats my mistake?

Comment: I guess the cpu overhead is too big. Better use instancing.

Comment: Not wrong, but 100k CPU to GPU round trips will be slow. Minecraft  will not draw each cube. rather it batches them together in a 'chunk' and draws big blocks all toegether. Also if you are drawing back to front you may be rendering alot of cubes that never get scene.

Comment: As a side note: DirectX 9 is deprecated. You wouldn't want to learn it in 2015. Learn DirectX 11 instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should make your vertex buffer static unless it requires to be dynamic. The GPU can use that information to help optimise.

While your graphics card can do many millions of triangles, it can't do many millions of draw calls. A single draw call is quite expensive, and later on you will try and minimise all state changes on the graphics card.

As mentioned in the comments instancing is one way to go to render many of the same thing. You could also actually merge all the cubes together and render in one shot (This is what Minecraft does to a degree).

There are other methods but it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Some are more involved than others.

Comment: Im trying to create so many rotating cubes (each on a different pos) as possible. I also want that i can move, scale and rotate every single cube. The problem is that i see no way to rotate, move, scale the single cubes if i put all into only one vertex buffer or index buffer. Sadly my book shows only how to create and draw a single cube. Is that what i want even possible while using vertex or index buffers?

Comment: @Bluefire Yes it is, I'm making a game with lots and lots of text. each character has its own position/texture/scale, but I render all the text in one call, with one buffer. You're after instancing.
http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter03.html
Thats just a round up on how instancing works.